# Aggregate conditional statements

Tags: r, conditional-statements, aggregate

I'm trying to find an elegant solution to a problem without complex subsetting and/or line by line iteration. I will explain via example:

```
# Load data
df1 <- mtcars

# Can aggregate with simple math functions i.e. mean or sum
hp_by_cyl <- aggregate(hp ~ cyl, data=df1, mean)
> hp_by_cyl
  cyl        hp
1   4  82.63636
2   6 122.28571
3   8 209.21429
```

Ok. But, in my real much more complex data I wish to aggregate a logical value - i.e. if x is true for any row belonging to category A then y =1. So to extend my example I can create a column with logical variable:

```
df1$logic <- ifelse(df1$gear==4 & df1$hp < 150, 1, 0)
# How do I aggregate the logical values levels of cyl to answer yes/no
# if any car with x cylinders has 4 gears and < 150 hp ?
# So I want an finished table like this:
cyl     logic
4       1
6       1
8       0
```

**So my question is how to use the aggregate (or alternate) command to produce a table like this ?** i.e. to combine the logical status, not the numeric value ?

I also need to deal with encoded missing values also in reality so to emulate that complexity I will make one of the logic's 99:

```
df1[5, ]$logic <- 99
```

If for a given level of `cyl` one value is 1, the 99 can be ignored - if however all others are 0 then the aggregate should be 99.

Apologies if there is a simple answer I don't see in my real data it seems daunting. I could hack out a nasty solution but I know it will be very slow and I have a 14000 X 140 size dataset. Thanks in advance all.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I have no idea how to code it to produce the summary table I want. Edited for clariaty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't bother with 0/1/99, just leave it TRUE/FALSE/NA.

```
df1$logic <- df1$gear==4 & df1$hp < 150
```

Then just aggregate with `any` or `tapply`.

```
aggregate(logic ~ cyl, data=df1, any)
##   cyl logic
## 1   4  TRUE
## 2   6  TRUE
## 3   8 FALSE

with(df1, tapply(logic, cyl, any))
##    4     6     8 
## TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

The plyr package, specifically the `ddply` function, is another option that many people find more intuitive.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df1, ~cyl, summarize, isany = any(gear==4 & hp < 150))
##  cyl isany
## 1   4  TRUE
## 2   6  TRUE
## 3   8 FALSE
```

Comment: Hi Aaron. Hmm yes that may work I'll try and let you know. Changing the 0/1/99 might be tricky since stuff inter-depends on it and I may need to distinguish between actual NA's and coded missings. I also came up with another solution but it is not as clean. `result <- aggregate(logic ~ cyl, data=df1, sum) ; result <- ifelse(result > 99, 1, result)`. This relies on there not being 99 1's of course! So as I say not as clean as yours

Comment: You should deal with your various kinds of missingness when you create your logic column so that the logic column itself can be TRUE/FALSE/NA.

Comment: If I have no mistakes previously it should not arise... So trying your method in live data but result is `.Primitive("any")` for every grouping variable. Not sure why can't see any obvious reason but I am still exploring it. EDIT: ok fixed it by taking out `function(x)` which I had left in for some reason. Ok thank you this solves my problem!!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you wanted:

```
aggregate(hp~cyl,data=mtcars,function(x) ifelse(mean(x)<150,1,0))
```

edit: 
`dplyr` is your friend:

```
mtcars %>% group_by_(~cyl) %>% summarise_(logic=~ifelse(mean(hp)<150 & sum(wt)>3,1,0))
```

This has a more complex logical statement so hopefully that helps. `aggregate` isn't the best approach if you want to handle more than 2 variables at a time.

Comment: Works in the toy example - will check in the main data and get back with confirmation/complications! Thanks for both clarifying my question and your answer!

Comment: `as.integer(mean(x) < 150)` could replace `ifelse()` for binary results and is more efficient.

Comment: Actually no - looking at it again - this is not the same. You have done a single test on the average. That works cause the example is crude, but its not how I posed it above where I deliberately set up a column of logical values. In the real data the `logic` column is the result of a whole bunch of work and can't be simplified as you have done it here

Comment: I'm not sure how to help unless you give a different example.

Comment: Sorry Carl my understanding has changed after posing the question. Thank you for your efforts. I think Aaron's solution will work if I modify some things before hand